# In-game text not showing up

Tags: technical-issues, counter-strike, ubuntu, counter-strike-condition-zero

I recently Installed Counter Strike on Ubuntu 13.10, but some of the text doesn't show up. The menus are fine, but then I have stuff like this:

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

I'm not running it under Wine or anything. Is this a problem with the game, or Ubuntu? Is there a way to fix it?

Counter Strike: Condition Zero has the same glitch, although some menus are fine; Day of Defeat renders all text perfectly.